# `timed`: how to act as NTP server?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, time, ntp

[I have two not-really-related questions about `timed`,
so I'm asking them separately.  The other one is
"[`timed` not always working?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/364892)".]

I just upgraded to High Sierra (yeah, I'm a bit behind the
times), and I just discovered this new system time daemon,
`timed`, which is evidently new with 10.13.
Unlike my previous Macs, this machine does not seem to be acting
as an NTP server -- that is, it is not accepting incoming NTP
connections on port 123, even from the local host.

I can see that it uses the configuration file `/etc/ntp.conf`,
and presumably if I put the right lines in there it might do
what I want, but I have no way of knowing whether it accepts all
the same directives there as `ntpd` does, so I'm afraid it may be
a bit of a crapshoot.  Anybody know of an "official" or sanctioned
way?  Right now `ntp.conf` consists of the single line

```
server time.apple.com.
```

(At the moment I only care about accepting NTP connections from
this machine, but eventually I may also want to accept them from
the local network.)

P.S. I was thinking there was a chance this might have something to do with firewall settings
("do/don't accept incoming connections"), although now I'm doubting that.  At @nohillside's suggestion, I tried fetching time on it (hitting it on NTP port 123) from an outside machine, and that failed, too.  (I've confirmed that I *can* fetch time by making NTP connections from this machine to other NTP servers, such as `time.apple.com`.)

Comment: Please add the content of your `ntp.conf`. Also, to check the firewall settings, can you verify that you can reach the time server using `ncat` or `telnet` from another system within your network?

Comment: @nohillside Question updated -- do those address your suggestions?

Comment: My bad, I thought you've already tried to change ntp.conf. Without any changes there, hitting port 123 won't work.